# panagram with less space and time complexity in java

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, time-complexity

I have implemented panagram program in O(n) time and space complexity. I want my program to be in O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity.

My steps are:

1. converting my string to character array.
2. adding all characters to Tree set (to avoid duplicates)
3. if size of tree set is 26 i am printing as panagram.

Is there any optimized way to reduce my space complexity to O(1)?

Comment: [Where should I post questions about algorithms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165519/273645): [Programmers SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165521/273645). Also see the [FAQ for Programmers SE](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on what can I ask here: `algorithm and data structure concepts`.

Comment: @TT. That meta post does not reflect actual practice -- Stack Overflow gets a much, much higher volume of algorithm questions (and not just "halp this code doesn't work") than Programmers (as it should IMHO -- the line just isn't as sharp as the meta posters with no actual tag experience want to believe).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yeah I get that, the lines are blurry. I just thought the chance of getting a good answer would be better over there.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to check, if you string is panagram.

If you avoid creation character array from string and iterate characters from original string, your complexity will be O(N*logA) time and O(A) space where A - alphabet size. In your case A is constant, so you will have O(N) time and O(1) space only if you rewrite your program with avoiding creation character array from string.

P.S. do not use tree for storing characters, it can be better to use array of size A to store how many times character is present in string. Even you can use bit array of size A, or A/8 of bytes count, to store if particular character is presented in string. And time complexity in this implementation will be O(N) not O(N*logA), but it doesn't matter much in complexity estimation, because A is constant, but even if so, plain array implementation will be faster (maybe several times faster) than storing presence of characters in tree.

Answer (score 0):

here I have modified the program to find the duplicate character in a String program from book `Cracking the coding interview` for your requirement using a bit vector.

Time complexity  O(n)
Space complexity O(1)

```
    String str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int checker = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
        checker |= (1 << val);
    }
    if (checker == 67108863)// 67108863 == 0b11111111111111111111111111
        System.out.println("Panagram");
    else
        System.out.println("Not Panagram");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can represent a character by one bit.

```
'a' -> 2^0 = 1
'b' -> 2^1 = 2
'c' -> 2^3 = 4
....
'z' -> 2^25
```

Then 26 characters are represented by 26bits.

```
static int ALL = (1 << 26) - 1;

public static boolean isPanagram(String s) {
    int aggregate = 0;
    for (int i = 0, size = s.length(); i < size; ++i) {
        char c = Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i));
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            aggregate |= 1 << (c - 'a');
    }
    return aggregate == ALL;
}
```

Comment: creating char array take additional space